# WordPress edit post or page that contain CSS will display 404 not found

Tags: html, css, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am working on a WordPress project. Wordpress displays 404 not found when update post or page.

Every time create or update (page/post) without css, It works, but it will display 404 not found (the link is www.website.com/wp-admin/post.php) when it having CSS (example change the color of text)

The css I mean here is

```
<p style="color:red">hello</p>
```

class as well not working

```
<p class = "red">class cannot as well</p>
```

Note:

1. Everything works well on localhost
2. Theme no problem, works well on localhost
3. It only happens when I put CSS or class name like `<p class = "xx">`, if no CSS inside the content, everything is fine
4. Sometimes only, after it displays 404 not found, the server will disconnect from FileZilla and cannot access the website (other device can access). But after restart router and keep refresh, everything fine again.

Comment: what is www.website.com/theme/post.php? shouldn't it be www.website.com/wp-admin/post.php?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Elvin85 yes. it is www.website.com/wp-admin/post.php. Thanks for correcting

Comment: @halfer Alright. thanks for your information.

Comment: Have you tried to change active theme to default theme and deactivate all plugins? If yes and the problem still exists, then you need to contact your hosting support.

Comment: Yes, I do. I did a fresh install with default WordPress file and new database. But the problem does not solve. Thanks anyway. 
Just curious, it is possible the problem come from the hosting?

Comment: my customer website hosting is from WordPress, he under WordPress paid plan.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Guys. I solved the problem by disabling the ModSecurity in Cpanel -> Security -> ModSecurity. I not sure what is the reason but anyway it's working.